# Get domain & subdomain of server by console application

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-server-2008, subdomain

Let's take one case that i hosted my web application on window server 2008 R2 and one exe (console application) running on that server.

I can access that web application by URI:

<**subdomain**>.<**domain**>.net , is there any way to get subdomain and domain info from EXE (C#) ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is... it depends.

If you only have one site hosted on your box then you can just connect to the local instance via either the IP Address the website on the machine resolves too, or by using http://localhost etc.

When you have a URL, the situation becomes more complicated. The machine could be hosting several websites - how do you know which one you want to connect to? In this instance, I would advise just storing the url you want to connect to in config.

However, it should be possible to list the all of the domains from IIS - [you'll need to use WMI](http://www.iisfaq.com/Default.aspx?tabid=3166).